# Why is my login function not working?

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
public static function validateLogin($username,$password)
    {
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->where('user_name=?',$username);
        $select->where('password=?',$password);
        $row = $this->fetchRow($select);
        If($row)
        {
            return $row;
        }

    }
```

This code doesn't work, help...

Comment: Is thow any exceptions or errors? Is result available with run in normal php. (Is data is available?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without using $this which does not have context in a static function.

You could use

`$model = new self;
$model->select();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be using [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html)?  Perhaps try this tutorial: http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/.

Zend_Auth is designed to handle authentication for you.

Comment: That works but I wanted to do it with a function in the model.